# How to create a bucket fill in Java?

Tags: java, paint, graphics2d, fill, bucket

I am trying to create a paint like program and I am currently implementing a bucket fill tool. I am storing all the points that have been drawn and using Graphics2D's `drawLine` to draw the actual lines, so I do not want to store all the points for the bucket fill (so I do not want to do flood fill).

For the bucket fill, so far I have used a `BufferedImage` to fill in the points that are not in my list, but are still being drawn.

One thing that I thought to do was to just store the outermost points that and than I could use Graphics2D's `fillPolygon` using those points. The only problem is that I'm not sure how to find those points.

I'm stuck here, so does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use collision points between lines. If there isn't one go back a segment and go to a different point if there is one. Keep adding those polygons. Include edges as segments.

Comment: I've now realized that this will not work out because there could be a color in the middle, and I do not want to paint over that. I am still curious about this, but I will not be using this anymore.

Comment: You could remove the polygon from the polygon you generate. That would be harder or you could record that polygon and use it to generate more segment to avoid overlapping.

Comment: @Legend You could create a `Area` using the first polygon and use `Area#subtract` to remove the second...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's probably a heap of different ways of achieving this, personally, I'd make use of 2D Graphics Shape API...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BucketFill {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BucketFill();
    }

    public BucketFill() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Point> points;

        public TestPane() {
            points = new ArrayList<Point>(25);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    points.add(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (points.size() > 0) {

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

                List<Point> proxy = new ArrayList<>(points);

                Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
                Point p = proxy.remove(0);
                path.moveTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
                while (proxy.size() > 0) {
                    p = proxy.remove(0);
                    path.lineTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
                }

                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.fill(path);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.draw(path);
                g2d.dispose();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update with fillPolygon**

You could replace the `Shape` implementation with a `fillPolygon` simply by removing the reference to the shape and using something like the following instead.

```
List<Point> proxy = new ArrayList<>(points);
int[] xPoints = new int[proxy.size()];
int[] yPoints = new int[proxy.size()];
int nPoints = proxy.size();

int index = 0;
while (proxy.size() > 0) {
    Point p = proxy.remove(0);
    xPoints[index] = p.x;
    yPoints[index] = p.y;
    index++;
}

g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2d.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
```

This will generate what's know as a closed polygon (ie, you can see that all the lines join up).

[image]

You can achieve using the `Shape` by calling `path.closePath()` after the `while-loop` and before it's painted.

**Updated with multiple Polygons**

[image]

A lot will come down to what you consider a polygon and how you store those values, but you could use an `Area` and subtract the intersecting polygon's from it...

```
public class BucketFill {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BucketFill();
    }

    public BucketFill() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<List<Point>> points;

        public TestPane() {
            points = new ArrayList<>(25);

            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    List<Point> newShape = new ArrayList<>(25);
                    newShape.add(e.getPoint());
                    points.add(newShape);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    List<Point> newShape = points.get(points.size() - 1);
                    newShape.add(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }
            };

            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (points.size() > 0) {

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>(25);
                for (List<Point> subPoints : points) {

                    if (subPoints.size() > 0) {

                        List<Point> proxy = new ArrayList<>(subPoints);

                        Path2D path = new Path2D.Float();
                        Point startPoint = proxy.remove(0);
                        path.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
                        for (Point p : proxy) {
                            path.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
                        }
                        path.closePath();
                        shapes.add(path);
                        path = null;

                    }

                }

                for (Shape master : shapes) {
                    Area area = new Area(master);
                    for (Shape inner : shapes) {
                        if (inner != master) {
                            area.subtract(new Area(inner));
                        }
                    }
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2d.fill(area);
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.draw(area);
                }

                g2d.dispose();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there is a hole in the points? This is user-input so there might not necessarily be a full polygon.

Comment: @Legend That's exactly what I just realized. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Legend Obviously missed part of the point.  Alot of this will come down to how to distinguish between the points and what makes a shape...

Comment: This is pretty neat (If I had the reputation I'd upvote it). There is only one problem I've found with it and that is that if you try to make another shape inside of a shape that is in a shape (so you have a red shape and you cut out a shape, and now you are trying to put a shape in there), it does not work.

Comment: @user2113611 Yeah, it's a pretty basic demo.  A lot comes down to how you define a polygon.  You could do a little more sophisticated checking then I've done, but the basic concept (generally) works...;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for good example, I've tried your method is working perfectly but when trying to draw another shape(like rect or cirle) after using this it breaks down in other shapes.How can I solve this please.

Comment: @CoderACJHP I guess that depends, are you using the `Shape`'s API or the primitives?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No I mean from Shapes 'figures' like Rectangle, Circle, Polygon, Ellipse2d, Line2D..

Comment: @MadProgrammer My project is here : https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/Paint.JAVA/blob/master/src/com/coder/paint/DrawGround.java

Comment: @CoderACJHP Well, `Rectangle`, `Circle`, `Ellipse2D` are all `Shape` based objects, so, techniqually, it should still work

Comment: Its woking good If you have not drawn anything in advance.Exaple : I draw a rectangle after that I need to fill it or drawing another figure with your tool it takes old mouse location points (width * height) and drawing big thick line.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can u browse please?https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/19620720/21786946/8fcc4888-d6d7-11e6-8f02-30cea907a431.png